# Como ocultar la mayor parte de un array en un div y hacer que se muestre completo con un boton "ver mas"

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks

Buen dia, estoy buscando la manera de hacer un div en el cual renderize un json array con map, este json es muy extenso por lo que quiero que se muestre solo las posiciones que tienen fecha actual las cuales serian talves seis u ocho, y el resto del array hacerlo accesible por medio de un boton "ver mas", el cual desplegaria de manera vertical la lista del array completo. ¿como podria hacerlo?.. agradezco su colaboracion.

Answer (score 0):

yo lo ingresaria en uuna grilla y realizaría un control de infinite scroll, entonces a media que el usuario va bajando vas sobrecargando el grid con nuevos objetos, por aquí te dejo un ejemplo de este control en react material

https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/row-updates/#infinite-loading

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda.